# Can we show that this series is uniformly convergent using Weierstrass-M test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $D$ be an open connected set. How can I show that the series
$$f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kz^k,$$
where $|z|<1$ for all $z\in D$ is uniformly convergent on $D$?

I wanted to use Weierstrass-M test but I can't find a convergent series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ such that $|kz^k|\leq a_k$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and all $z\in D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not uniformly convergent in $D$. If it is, there would be an integer $m$ such that $|kz^{k}| <1$ for all $z \in D$ for all $k \geq m$. Letting $z\to 1$ we get $k \leq 1$ for all $k \geq m $ which is absurd.

[If $s_n$ is the $n-$th partial sum of the series the $kz^{k}=s_k-s_{k-1}$. This proves the existence of $m$].

Comment: Does this mean that $f(z)$ is not holomorphic?

Comment: It is holomorphic because the convergence is uniform on $\{z:|z|\leq 1-\epsilon\}$ for any $\epsilon >0$. @theinnerbeauty